# Create Custom Attachment Template That is Processed from Plugin Folder?

Tags: themes, templates

I have made a custom image.php for a gallery plugin I'm creating.  My dilemma is that I currently have to have my customized image.php in the theme folder for it to work.  Is there a way to tell Wordpress to utilize a template file outside of the theme folder to process attachments?

Answer (score 1):

Filter `attachment_template` and return your custom path. For details, see `wp-includes/template.php`, function `get_query_template()`.

Sample code:

```
add_filter( 'attachment_template', function( $template )
{
    global $post;

    // inspect $post object to determine the correct template
    // and change the file path, then:
    return $template;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it first looks in theme folder if not found then in plugins folder.

**Sample code:**

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'weinvent_template_redirect' );

/*Template fallback*/
function weinvent_template_redirect() {

    global $wp, $wp_query;
    $plugindir  =   dirname( __FILE__ );

    if( is_attachment() ) {
        $templatefilename   =   'image.php';
        if( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templatefilename ) )  {
            $return_template    =   TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $templatefilename;    
        }   else    {
            $return_template    =   $plugindir . '/templates/' . $templatefilename;
        }

        do_theme_redirect( $return_template );
    }              

}

function do_theme_redirect( $url ) {

    global $post, $wp_query;
    if( have_posts() )  {
        include($url);
        die();
    }   else    {
        $wp_query->is_404   =   true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not good: 1. `template_redirect` runs on _every_ template, so the callback is called too often. 2. your `die()` prevents the important action `shutdown`, so this will break many plugins.